# BufferManager calling TakeBuffer without calling ReturnBuffer

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone please explain to me why the following works for far more than one iteration:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BufferManager _bufferManager = BufferManager.CreateBufferManager(100, 100);
            int count = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] b = _bufferManager.TakeBuffer(100);
                Console.WriteLine("Bytes taken: {0}", ++count * 100);
            }
        }
```

I'm expecting the buffer manager to throw an OutOfMemoryException or something like that, as I've allocated only 100 bytes to its pool. And yet this loop will take many megabytes without an issue.

Am I missing something? Does that mean that calling ReturnBuffer is optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MaxBufferPoolSize and MaxBufferSize don't refer to what you think.

Take a look at the answer here, which explains it much better than I could!

[MaxBufferPoolSize vs MaxBufferSize](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6e234d3-942f-4e9d-8470-32618d3f3212/maxbufferpoolsize-vs-maxbuffersize)